# JQuery and Typescript click() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript

Ok so I have two JQuery functions inside a Typescript-file:

```
            $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
            }

            console.log('Scroll');
        });

        //Click event to scroll to top
        $('#scrollToTopButton').on('click', function () {
            console.log("Click");
        })
```

The window scroll function works perfectly. However I don't get the click-event working. I tried `$('#scrollToTopButton').click(function(){ ...` and so on, doesn't seem to work. Here is the html:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn scrollToTop" id="scrollToTopButton">
```

Comment: is button element rendered when you are trying to bind the event ? you should have this js after button element or in document ready function.

Comment: if you are handling all such things from jquery then what's the point of using angularJS

Comment: Tried putiting it inside the document ready function. Still no difference

Comment: @Shashank I just want to implement a small button, which appears on every page. I think it's less effort to do this with JQuery

Comment: Is `#scrollToTopButton` part of Angular template or it is outside of the app area?

Comment: I don't think that the OP is using angular. I don't see it anywhere in his post.

Answer (score 0):

> so on, doesn't seem to work.

It should work. A few tips for debugging

- add `console.log($('#scrollToTopButton'))`
- Check that you closed the `button` tag.
- Use an html validator to make sure the html is valid.